# How to calculate launch angle and launch heading to shoot into a target while moving?

Tags: math, physics, robotics

I am trying to find the launch angle and launch heading to hit a specific point at the end of the trajectory. However the challenge is that the shooter is translating along the field. Therefore there is a momentum that influences the trajectory and curves it into the 3rd dimension. Again, I need to calculate the launch angle compared to the horizon and the launch heading to counter the momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a programing question let me explain it to you. To work out a projectile motion in 2D, we usually break the velocity vector into two components v<sub>x</sub> and v<sub>z</sub> and launch angle θ<sub>xz</sub>. To work it out in 3D you'll just need to do the same things in 3D i.e. you'll need to resolve the velocity vector into three components v<sub>x</sub>, v<sub>y</sub> and v<sub>z</sub> along with launch angles in two direction θ<sub>xz</sub> and θ<sub>yz</sub> and also an angle θ<sub>xy</sub>. After that, you can apply your normal equations of motion to get a proper solution. Now, the problem remains to get the velocity. That can be done by considering a frame of reference and relative velocity vectors. Do these two things and you'll get your answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the shooter moves according to some trajectory equations

```
x(t) = [x[0](t), x[1](t), 0]
```

in the horizontal plane (that is why `x[3](t) = 0` because the trajectory is always on the plane `x[1], x[2]`).
At time `t_0` the shooter is at the point `x_0 = x(t_0)` and has velocity

```
v_0 = v(t_0) = dx/dt(t_0) = [v_0[0], v_0[1], 0]
```

I assume you know the magnitude of the velocity `w > 0` with which the bullet is shot at time `t_0` and you are looking for a directing unit vector

```
u = [u[0], u[1], u[2]]
1 = u[0]^2 + u[1]^2 + u[2]^2
```

that will guarantee that the shot will hit the stationary (I hope) target located at point

```
x_1 = [x_1[0], x_1[1], x_1[2]]
```

So the shot is fired at time `t_0` from point `x_0`, the latter moving with speed `v_0` and the magnitude of the fired bullet is `w`. Therefore the initial velocity of the bullet with respect to a coordinate system attached to the ground is `v_0 + w*u`, where `u` is the unknown unit vector. The vectorized differential equations of motion are

```
dx/dt = v

dv/dt = - g * e_3
```

where `e_3 = [0, 0, 1]` and `g = 9.8`. The solution of these equations, that starts from `x_0` with velocity `v_0 + w*u` at time `t_0` follows the trajectory described by the vectorized equations

```
x(t) = x_0 + (t - t_0) * (v_0 + w*u) - g*(t - t_0)^2 * e_3
```

So, there is a yet unknown moment of time `t_1` at which the bullet hits the target `x_1`, i.e.

```
x_1 = x(t_1) which yields

x_1 =  x_0 + (t_1 - t_0) * (v_0 + w*u) - g*(t_1 - t_0)^2 * e_3
```

Denote by

```
x_10 = x_1 - x_0  (known) i.e.

for (int i=0; i<3; i++){x_12[i] = x_1[i] - x_0[i]}

t_10 = t_1 - t_0  (unknown)
```

Then you get

```
x_10 = t_10 * (v_0 + w*u) - g * (t_10)^2 * e_3
```

If you rewrite the vectorized equation of the bullet hitting the target componentwise, you get the following system of four quadratic  equations for the unknown variables `t_10, u[0], u[1], u[2]`:

```
x_10[0] = t_10 * ( v_0[0] + w*u[0] )
x_10[1] = t_10 * ( v_0[1] + w*u[1] )
x_10[2] = t_10 * w * u[1]  -  (t_10)^2 * g / 2
1 = u[0]^2 + u[1]^2 + u[2]^2
```

If you express the variables `u[0], u[1], u[2]` in terms of `t_12` from the first three equations, you get

```
u[0] = x_10[0]/(w*t_10) - v[0]/w
u[1] = x_10[1]/(w*t_10) - v[1]/w
u[2] = ( x_10[2] + (t_10)^2 * g / 2 )/(w*t_10)
1 = u[0]^2 + u[1]^2 + u[2]^2
```

then you can plug the expressions for `u[0], u[1], u[2]` in terms of `t_12` into the last equation and you get, after multiplying both sides by `(t_10)^2`, a degree four polynomial equation in the variable `t_12`. After you solve it, you will find one positive root and you can plug it back in the first three equations to calculate the coordinates of the unit vector `u`.